# Why is my font not rendering correct / fuzzy - is there a way to fix this?

Tags: css, fonts

I am using various versions of Halvetic on this website. For some reason they all display fine, except for one which is fuzzy. I have noticed that one some browsers it is better or worse - however, on my iPhone it is really crisp and perfect?

Are there any suggestions on how I can get this font to display correctly in modern browsers on a desktop (chrome/firefox etc)?

This is what I see:
[image: screenshot of fuzzy font rendering]

**URL: http://52.64.135.79/wordpress/company-overview/**

Relevant CSS rules I can see are as follows. Is there something I can do to fix this?

```
h4, .h4 {
    line-height: 21px;
}
h4, .h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
}
h4, .h4 {
    font-weight: 700;
}
h4, .h4 {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue LT W01_55 Roman", sans-serif !important;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px 0 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.00em;
}

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Different platforms and browsers have different font rendering. Can you tell us on what platforms / browsers and on what DPI you observe the poor rendering? But I guess these are just platform limitations or bad system settings, so not much you can do about it as a web developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately the issue here was because the font itself has a separate character set for each different font weight. 
The CSS was applying a font-weight of 700 to a font which was meant to be rendered at 400. The fix was to download the heavier weight version of the font, rather than allow the browser to create an artificial "bold" version.